# Laravel file manager illegal offset type

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-manager

I'm trying to install the Laravel file manager to my Laravel 5.0 app. It installs without problem with composer.

I add service providers to config/app.php

```
Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

but when I Publish the package's config and assets :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

am getting an error.

```
  Illegal offset type
```

I can't seem to find where the mistake is. Thanks guys.

Comment: did you tried to publish all the assets? `php artisan vendor:publish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a repo with laravel-filemanager integrated.
https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager-example-5.3
Please go to `localhost:8000/laravel-filemanager/demo` and see if there is any error.